# Getting a value from another table for multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a table City with two fields, CityCode and RegionCode
I have another table Code with two fields Code and CodeMeaning

I want to write a select statement that will display both cityCode, regionCode and their meanings for each city.

If i had to get one meaning from Code table i could do it with join but i don't know how to get values for both columns.

```
City Table Data
------------------------
CityCode     RegionCode
34             53
41             43

Code Table Data
-----------------
Code        Meaning
34          New York
41          Boston
53          North
43          South


Desired Output
------------------
CityCode     RegionCode    Region   City
34             53          North    New York
41             43          South    Boston
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. Are you using SQL server? Oracle? MySql? Sample data demonstrating the relationships between the tables and an example of what you want the query to produce would be helpful too.

Comment: @YogeshSharma I added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two joins:

```
select cc.meaning as city, cr.meaning as region
from city c left join
     code cc
     on c.citycode = cc.code left join
     code cr
     on c.regioncode = cr.code
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a bit poor db design but you can get the data with 2 joins to the codes table:

```
select c.*, c1.data as city, c2.data as region
from city_table c
join code_table c1 on c1.code = c.city_code
join code_table c2 on c2.code = c.region_code
```